# Mysql tables missing after Docker update: "TableName doesn't exist in engine"

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, docker-for-mac

A recent Docker update seems to have caused (just some) InnoDB tables in a MariaDB to not be accessible. I get:

`#1932 - Table 'dbname.SomeTableName' doesn't exist in engine`

when trying to access them (they do SHOW up in a table list). I've updated Docker (and the image) in the past with no problem. The db files and permissions look fine.

I could recreate just the "missing" tables (4 out of ~35) from a backup, but when I try to delete them I get:

`#1347 - 'dbname.SomeTableName' is not VIEW`

I'm using Docker image `mariadb:10.2` (MariaDB-10.2.12+maria~jessie) with a bind-mount for persistent data storage as part of a local Docker-for-Mac dev environment. The docker-compose.yml file looks like:

`mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.2
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`

I've never had this error before and cannot dump or export the unaccessible tables. Is there a way to restore or repair (or delete) them? I would rather not have to recreate the entire database.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I think this squarely falls under "directly involve tools used primarily for programming", and there are plenty of other questions about MySql config here.

Comment: Actually, it does not. Docker is just another lightweight VM like Debian chroot's. Docker is supposed to be used for API questions, but Stack Overflow has become a dumping ground for the questions.

Comment: Turns out it it was only indirectly a Docker problem, does that change things for you? Docker was just involved as it contributed to updating the MariaDB version -- similar to if it had been yum or apt. Again, I'm running a very common _development_ setup so I have to think it's possible it's happened to some other people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using a custom mysql config for my local and adding:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

You can do this without changing your default config by mounting a file containing the text above into the mysql conf.d directory like:

```
volumes:
  - ./mysql_local.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql_local.cnf:ro
```

Comment: Since this solved the problem and it's one others may run into, not sure why you would downvote.

Comment: I ran into this problem after updating my Docker installation. I am really curious what might have caused this change. Any ideas? Reading the docs for the setting you have provided didn't shed too much light for me... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names

Comment: I was never able to definitively tell what caused it but I noticed the tables that were missing used upper-case letters (created by a 3rd-party module, mine are lower-case). I assume the Docker update triggered an image update and having data bind-mounted to a non-case sensitive volume while running on a case-sensitive one may have caused the issue. Why it wasn't a problem prior, I can't say. I did change my image to include the minor version, e.g., `image: mariadb:10.2.12` -- although it's also possible the Docker update changed something related to the filesystem.

Comment: You can also fix this using adding the following entry

        command: --lower_case_table_names=1

Comment: Sory, but this `lower_case_table_names=1` option doesn't fix the issue. And my tables are in the lowercase already.

Comment: It works for me, thank you so much! I am running Docker in Mac OS and after altering table it breaks. My tables also contains uppercase letters. I added `--lower_case_table_names=1` to `command` section in `docker-compose.yml`.